# Can CSS display images at fractions of their original size?

Tags: css

The following CSS style dictates that an image that's 400 pixels wide will appear to be 200 pixels wide if it's placed in a div measuring 400 pixels...

```
img { width: 50%; }
```

But is there a style that makes an image display at half its own size, regardless of the container it's in?

I'm asking this because I have a lot of floated image slices to work with. For example, suppose you take an image of a dinosaur that's 400 pixels wide and slice it into quarters horizontally. The four resulting images might measure 350px, 300px, 280px and 200px. If I want to display them in a mobile device, I have to create separate styles for each piece, setting the width at half of the original width, one third the original width, or whatever.

So I just wondered if there's some sort of style I could use that would automatically reduce each image by a third, a half, etc. Thanks.

Comment: does your slices have a similar width , height or is it kind of a puzzle ?  if they all have same height or same width then they can easily be rescaled taking 100% width or height of one single container. to pile them it wouldbe: display:block; + width:100%; to set them side by side , it would be float + height:100%; . it will take container size

Comment: Good tip, but it's more of a puzzle. However, in the future I'll have to try to make the slices the same height. I didn't know you could scale images by height like that.

Answer (score 0):

> But is there a style that makes an image display at half its own size, regardless of the container it's in?

I can’t think of one simple property for the image itself – but if you place them in an element with `display:inline-block`, you’ll get exactly what you want:

```
<div style="width:400px"><span><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"></span></div>
<div style="width:600px"><span><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"></span></div>
<div style="width:800px"><span><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"></span></div>

div { background:red; }
span { display:inline-block; }
img { width:50%; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H8AQY/